# I am unable to display the results I am looking for from api, TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '... this.state.fantasyName.map ...')

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I want to get some names that are in an api, this api returns a json and I want to make map () to display all the names I need, when I display this map () inside a console.warn () it returns all right results, but when I try to pass the results to a state and try to use it in the render () give an error

> 'TypeError: Undefined is not a function (near' ... this.state.fantasyName.map ... ') error

where am i going wrong?

tried in other ways more blank returns, less in console.warn ()

```
   componentDidMount() {
        AsyncStorage.getItem('token').then((value) => this.setState({ token: 
        'Bearer ' + value }));

        const uri = "http://192.168.0.149/xpago- 
        backoffice/api/participant/getparticipant.php"

        const requestInfo = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: new Headers({
                'Content-type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': this.state.token
            })
        }

        fetch(uri, requestInfo)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {

                this.setState({fantasyName: responseJson})

            })
    }

    renderList() {
        const name = this.state.fantasyName.map(nomes => {
            const nf = nomes.PAR_FANTASYNAME;
            return <Text key={nf}>{nf}</Text>
        }) 
        return name;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <LinearGradient colors={['#41295a', '#2f0743']} style={{ 
                  height: 690 }}>
                    <View style={style.fundo}>
                        <StatusBar translucent backgroundColor='transparent' 
                        />
                        <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.voltar}>
                            <Image
                                source={require('../images/voltar.png')}
                                style={style.voltar}
                            />
                        </TouchableHighlight>
                        <Text style={style.tit}>Cadastros</Text>
                    </View>
                    <ScrollView>
                        {this.renderList()}
                    </ScrollView>
                    <TouchableOpacity style={style.add1} onPress= 
                     {this.cadastro}>
                        <View>
                            <Image source={require('../images/add.png')} 
                             style={style.add} />
                        </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </LinearGradient>
            </View>

        )
    }
```

I need my json results to be displayed inside scrollView

i'm new to react-native can you help me?

Comment: How you defined your `state` variable ? `fantasyName` should be array. Declare `fantasyName: []` if not defined

Comment: Try this `{this.state.fantasyName && this.state.fantasyName.length && this.renderList()}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How is your state being initialized? Anyway, you shall keep in mind that `this.renderList()` is being called before the `componentDidMount` method. In those cases, you have to "manage" when the function should be called. In your case you can do:

```
   <ScrollView>
     {this.state.fantasyName.length && this.renderList()}
   </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Retrieving from AsyncStorage is an async call, I would suggest using

```
let token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
```

Secondly, please put a .catch at the end of fetch after then clause to catch any errors in the fetch request. What is the response you are getting from the API? Could you post that?
My guess is that the API call you are making is to an http source which is not trusted by React Native, I would suggest using rn-fetch-blob, for this purpose.